# How to share sub directory with specific users

Tags: git, github

In my github private repository, I have those directories :

- dirA
- dirB
- dirC

Is it possible to share the dirA only with user 1 and the dirB only with user 2?

Comment: No. Git doesn't do fine-grained access control (by design). Especially read access is usually all-or-nothing. Submodules might allow you to move dirA and dirB into their own dedicated repositories and share those, but that also comes with its own set of problems.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+fine-grained+access+control